# How to test if application is using bootstrap 4?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am new to angular development and I am developing an angular 6 app. The tutorial is using BootStrap 4 CSS. However, the same css is not working as expected for me. I want to know how I can check if my application is using the Bootstrap 4 CSS.

Comment: Check with your browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

In `package.json` file under dependencies check which version of bootstrap you have installed.

[image]